# Retrieving dbpedia-owl:type value of resource with dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirect value?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, linked-data

Visitng http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cupertino shows the DBpedia RDF information about Cupertino. As you can see, it has, among others, the property and value:

```
dbpedia-owl:type  dbpedia:City
```

However, this query on the DBpedia endpoint returns no results:

```
SELECT ?type  WHERE {
  dbpedia:Cupertino  dbpedia-owl:type ?type
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=%20%20%20%20SELECT%20?type%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia%3aCupertino%20%20dbpedia-owl%3atype%20?type%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Why can't I retrieve the value of the `dbpedia-owl:type` property?

Comment: http://dbpedia.org/ontology/type thats the kind of type property whith which "City" is assigned to "Cupertino", so I should be using the correct property URI... or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an interactive webservice in front of you, and one of the most useful things that you can do  is *generalize* your query into one that should return a superset of the results you're looking for, as a sort of sanity check.  In this case, it's useful to see what happens if you ask for *all* properties and values of `dbpedia:Cupertino`.

```
select ?p ?o where {
  dbpedia:Cupertino ?p ?o 
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?p%20?o%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aCupertino%20?p%20?o%20%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
p                                               o
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Settlement
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://schema.org/Place
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID          337802
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRevisionID  16202923
http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label      "Cupertino"@en
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cupertino,_California
http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/isPrimaryTopicOf      http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupertino
http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#wasDerivedFrom        http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupertino?oldid=16202923
```

In this case, that `dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects` is very important.  When you type in `dbpedia:Cupertino` or the full URI, http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cupertino, into a web browser, look carefully at where you end up.  You end up at http://dbpedia.org/page/Cupertino,_California, which means that the resource you're actually asking about is http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cupertino,_California (when you retrieve them in a browser, you're redirected from `/resource/` to `/page/`, but the naming convention is still the same.

To use `dbpedia:Cupertino` in a query, you'd need to add the redirect information.  Thus, you could use the following query to get the results that you're looking for:

```
select ?type where {
  dbpedia:Cupertino dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects*/dbpedia-owl:type ?type
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?type%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aCupertino%20dbpedia-owl%3awikiPageRedirects%2a/dbpedia-owl%3atype%20?type%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Thanks, I noticed the redirect too in the browser URL, but I had no idea there was a property for that! Are there diferent 'kinds' of redirects? Like 'dbpedia-ontology:wikiPagesRedirects' and other variatons?

Comment: select ?type where {
  http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cupertino   http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects*/http://dbpedia.org/ontology/type   ?type
} Do you know why this query won't work then?

Comment: Code is next to unreadable in comments, and URI formatting is particularly problematic.  Isn't that the same as the last query that I included in my answer?  At any rate, `select ?type where { 
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cupertino> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects>*/<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/type> ?type
} ` works just fine.

Comment: It is the same indeed. Yes it's unreadable, but I thought answering my own question was 'bad style' too. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, thats exactly what I needed - I was missing the "<>".

Comment: I'm surprised that you didn't get a parse error if you were missing some brackets!

Comment: The brackets are missing due to the auto-formatting of the comments on SO.

Comment: @user3641140 That doesn't surprise me, but it highlights why you should use backticks (`\``) around code and code-like text.  You can write `select ?type where { <…> … }`.