# Obtain linked resources with SPARQL query on DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Hello everybody i'm using a SPARQL query to retrieve properties and values of a specified resource. For example if i ask for Barry White, i obtain: birth place, associatedBand, recordLabels and so on.

Instead for any instance such as "Hammerfall", i obtain only this results:
[Query results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20db%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20prop%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20onto%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fvalue%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20db%3AHammerfall%3Fproperty%20%3Fvalue%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

But i want properties and values as shown in this page: [Correct results](http://dbpedia.org/page/HammerFall).

My query is:

```
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?property ?value
WHERE { db:Hammerfall?property ?value  }
```

Anyone can tell me how to access to the correct resource and obtain corrects properties and values in every case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ?p ?o { dbpedia:HammerFall ?p ?o }
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%7B%20dbpedia%3AHammerFall%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The particular prefix doesn't matter;  I just used dbpedia: because it's predefined on the endpoint as http://dbpedia.org/resource/, just like your db:.  The issue is that HammerFall has a majuscule F in the middle, but your query uses a miniscule f.

As an alternative, since the results for Hammerfall (with a miniscule f) do include

> http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects     http://dbpedia.org/resource/HammerFall

you could use a property path to follow any wikiPageRedirects paths:

```
select ?p ?v {
  dbpedia:Hammerfall dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects* ?hammerfall .
  ?hammerfall ?p ?v 
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fp%20%3Fv%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3AHammerfall%20dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageRedirects*%20%3Fhammerfall%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fhammerfall%20%3Fp%20%3Fv%20%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

See [Retrieving dbpedia-owl:type value of resource with dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirect value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23871225/1281433) for more about that approach.