# SPARQL for direct dbpedia resource OR wikiPageRedirects

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to query data from dbpedia by a country's name. I want it to find it whether there is a resource for that country or via its existence in wikiPageRedirects. Here is a working version:

```
PREFIX res: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX ont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?country ?capital ?label 
WHERE {
    { res:Dominion_of_Canada ont:capital ?capital .
    ?capital rdfs:label ?label }
UNION
    { res:Dominion_of_Canada ont:wikiPageRedirects ?country .
    ?country ont:capital ?capital .
    ?capital rdfs:label ?label }

FILTER (lang(?label) = "en") 
}
```

I'd like (if possible), to factor out the ?country. Is it possible to assign a resource to a variable such that the SPARQL query looks like the following?

```
SELECT ?country ?capital ?label
WHERE {
{ ?country EXISTS res:Dominion_of_Canada } # to get the idea across
UNION
{ res:Dominion_of_Canada ont:wikiPageRedirects ?country }

?country ont:capital ?capital .
?capital rdfs:label ?label .
FILTER (lang(?label) = "en")
}
```

As ever, speed is important, too. If the resource exists, then it'd be better if it skipped searching on wikiPageRedirects.

Comment: Does the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871225/retrieving-dbpedia-owltype-value-of-resource-with-dbpedia-owlwikipageredirect help?

Comment: Thanks, Joshua. That part of the query is already working. I added some more details to the main question above.

Comment: I don't see a query there..., but it's usually easier to post code as updates to questions.

Comment: *"I'd like it to use res:France as the variable ?country if that resource exists."*  The part about "if that resource exists" isn't quite well defined.  the URI `res:France` exists,  it's just a constant value, just like a number exists, or a string exists.  I think you mean, though (and please correct me if I misunderstand), that you want to use res:France if it has the properties you're looking for, but otherwise, use a page that res:France redirects to.  I think that the question I originally linked to may help there.

Comment: Heh, you responded quickly! My edits are now finished. I hope that's more clear. I'm not concerned about the existence of any qualities at this point - just finding the actual dbpedia resource I'm looking for. The above query works, but I'm wondering if I can factor out the ?capital and ?label lines in this way.

Comment: Have a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31456508/1281433).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking whether a resource "exists" or not is a bit vague, since IRIs are just constant data.  The question is really whether DBpedia contains any triples about a particular resource.  In your case, you're wanting to know whether it it redirects to anything else, or if it has properties of its own.  A property path of the form **dbpedia:France dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects* ?country** is really probably the best way to do that.  If there are no redirect links, then **?country** is **dbpedia:France**, and if there are, then **?country** is the value of the redirects.  The only way to "check" is to look for those triples.  I think that means you will end up with something like this (similar to what's shown in my answer to [another question involving redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871225/retrieving-dbpedia-owltype-value-of-resource-with-dbpedia-owlwikipageredirect)):

```sql
select ?country ?anthem ?author {
  #-- The only way to really "check" that the resource 
  #-- "exists" and is not a redirect, is by checking 
  #-- whether it has any redirect links.  If it doesn't,
  #-- then ?country is dbpedia-owl:France, like you want
  #-- and if it does, then then you want to follow them.
  dbpedia:France dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects* ?country .

  #-- I'm using anthem and author here because 
  #-- it doesn't look like there was reliable information
  #-- about the capital.
  ?country dbpedia-owl:anthem ?anthem .                  
  ?anthem dbpprop:author ?author .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fcountry%20%3Fanthem%20%3Fauthor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20The%20only%20way%20to%20really%20%22check%22%20that%20the%20resource%20%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20%22exists%22%20and%20is%20not%20a%20redirect%2C%20is%20by%20checking%20%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20whether%20it%20has%20any%20redirect%20links.%20%20If%20it%20doesn%27t%2C%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20then%20%3Fcountry%20is%20dbpedia-owl%3AFrance%2C%20like%20you%20want%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20and%20if%20it%20does%2C%20then%20then%20you%20want%20to%20follow%20them.%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3AFrance%20dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageRedirects*%20%3Fcountry%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20I%27m%20using%20anthem%20and%20author%20here%20because%20%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20it%20doesn%27t%20look%20like%20there%20was%20reliable%20information%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20about%20the%20capital.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20dbpedia-owl%3Aanthem%20%3Fanthem%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Fanthem%20dbpprop%3Aauthor%20%3Fauthor%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Hot damn! That did it, and simplified the query quite a bit. What does the * signify? 

(and you were right - that other answer was similar, though I didn't see how it was working)

Comment: @Bonjiro The `*` is one of the [property paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) supported in SPARQL 1.1.  The pattern `a p* b` matches if there's a *path* from a to b consisting of zero or more occurrences of `p`.  In the case that the path if of length zero, it means that a and b have to be the same.  E.g., `x hasChild* ?y` would bind `?y` to `x` and all of `x`'s descendants.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

select dbr:France ?capital ?label where {
  {dbr:France a dbpedia-owl:Country.
   dbr:France dbpedia-owl:capital ?capital .
   ?capital rdfs:label ?label .
  }

 union {dbr:France dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects ?redirectPage.
        ?redirectPage dbpedia-owl:capital ?capital.
        ?capital rdfs:label ?label .     
 }
}
```

[Result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20dbr%3AFrance%20%3Fcapital%20%3Flabel%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7Bdbr%3AFrance%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ACountry.%0D%0A%20%20%20dbr%3AFrance%20dbpedia-owl%3Acapital%20%3Fcapital%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fcapital%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20union%20%7Bdbr%3AFrance%20dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageRedirects%20%3FredirectPage.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FredirectPage%20dbpedia-owl%3Acapital%20%3Fcapital.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcapital%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Hi Ali. I clarified the question. It's a matter of if it's possible to factor out the ?country portion by assigning the resource to a variable if it exists.